# How to use node-set function in a platform-independent way?

Tags: xml, cross-platform, msxml, xslt

I'm writing some xlst file which I want to use under linux and Windows. 
In this file I use node-set function which declared in different namespaces for MSXML and xsltproc ("urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" and "http://exslt.org/common" respectively). Is there any platform independent way of using node-set?

Comment: Hi Евгений, See my answer that provides the needed info for a single universal implementation of the xxx:node-set() function. Cheers

Answer (score 8):

You can use the function function-available() to determine which function you should use:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="function-available('exslt:node-set')">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($nodelist)" />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="function-available('msxsl:node-set')">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($nodelist)" />
  </xsl:when>
  <!-- etc -->
</xsl:choose>
```

You can even wrap this logic in a named template and call it with the nodeset as a parameter.

Answer (score 8):

**Yes, there is a good and universal solution**.

[**EXSLT**](http://exslt.org/)'s function [**common:node-set()**](http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html) can be implemented as an inline Javascript function and is thus available with any browser that supports Javascript (practically all major browsers without exception).

This technique was first discovered by [**Julian Reschke**](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/) and after he published it on the [**xsl-list**](http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/), was publicized by [**David Carlisle**](http://dpcarlisle.blogspot.com/). On the [**blog of David Carlisle**](http://dpcarlisle.blogspot.com/2007/05/exslt-node-set-function.html) there is also a link to a test page that shows if the common:node-set() function thus implemented works with the browser of your choice.

To summarize:

1. First go [**here**](http://dpcarlisle.blogspot.com/2007/05/exslt-node-set-function.html) and read the explanation.
2. Then try the test page. In particular, verify that it works with IE (that means with MSXML)
3. Finally, use the code.

Do enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

[Exslt](http://www.exslt.org) is "supposed to be" a platform-independent set of xslt extensions, but only so far as various xslt processors choose to implement them.

There's [some evidence](http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000559.html) that MSXML actually does support exsl:node-set(), but I don't know for sure.

There is an [old article](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/08/06/exslt.html) discussing [an implementation](http://fxsl.sourceforge.net/) of exslt on top of MSXML.

Otherwise, I think function-available() is your friend :)

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 3 implements node-set (as part of the EXSLT 2.0 namespace improvements) in it's client-side XSLT processing.

Maybe not quite the answer you were looking for - but it could be, depending on the context of your problem. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If there is not a particular reason to use msxml implementation of node-set on windows you coul use exslt one everywhere, by including the implemenation downloaded from http://exslt.org with your stylesheet, [exslt howto](http://exslt.org/howto.html) describes the needed steps. You can use either "Extension namespaces" way or "Named templates" way.