# XSLT Document Function - Folder Hierarchy

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am working with xslt 1.0 and trying to use the XSLT document function to apply the stylesheet to a hierarchy of folders. The folder structures is as below, but I cannot seem to find any reliable references on the Web on how to do this.

```
a/
└── b
    └── c
        ├── d
        ├── e
        ├── f
```

Is there a way I can apply my stylesheet to nodes, in a file, in folder f via a file in folder a (a has links to file names in folder hierarchy).

**Update #2**

```
book01.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<book location="../collection/book01.xml">
    <chapter>chapter001</chapteer>
</book>

chapter01.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<chapter location="../collection/book01/chapter01.xml">
    <page>page01</page>
</chapter>

page01.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<page location="../collection/book01/chapter01/page01.xml">
    <pagenumber>page 1</pagenumber>
    <text>
      page one.
    </text>
</page>

Output

Book Name: Book XX
  Chapter XX
    Page XX
      page xx.
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that my initial plan was to work with for-each elements, but not quite sure if nesting the elements could help... perhaps its something I ought to try out.

   <xsl:for-each>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="document()"/>
   </xsl:for-each>

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: Do you need to apply the same stylesheet to a set of files and get a different output for each one of them also? I mean do you need a result document each time the transform is applied?

Comment: @empo: I am using xsltproc and yes, the idea is to apply the same stylesheet. The folder hierarchy is such that the information only makes sense when combined from the hierarchy, so I need the stylesheet applied recursively in a way.

Comment: Can you provide a small but meaningful example of file a and f and a sample output?

Comment: @empo: please see update #2 in original post. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a feasable/reasonable way to implement what you want achieve in the context of your use case; however, you can stay with you initial plan, that is working with `xsl:for-each` and `document()`.

For example, assume you have the input file with the list of paths:

```
<files>
    <file>book001.xml</file>
    <file>chapter001.xml</file>
</files>
```

This input can be reasonably used to define a variable containing all your input documents and apply templates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="files">
        <xsl:variable name="docs">
            <docs>
                <xsl:for-each select="file">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="document(.)"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </docs>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($docs)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- now you can match elements of your xml files -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notice that I needed the extension function in order to evaluate to a node-set. This is definetly available in **xsltproc**, or you can get it from EXSLT anyway.

In the example I've assumed that the input file is in the same folder of the book001.xml and chapter001.xml file.

Comment: I will try this out; Thank you. What would be a feasible/reasonable way of tackling such a problem? any suggestions on how I can go about this?
PS: I am working on a linux machine; I am assuming msxsl will only work with Windows... am I right?

Comment: This is might be a reasonable way if fits your requirements :), and no, apart the msxsl node-set extension it will work on any system. You have the same kind of extensions in xsltproc anyway.

Comment: For node-set via EXSLT you can see the @Dimitre answer to this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92076/how-to-use-node-set-function-in-a-platform-independent-way).

Answer (score 0):

If the links are relative then they are resolved against the base URI of the initial stylesheet, so that might not work. In XSLT 2.0 you have the `resolve-uri` function for that.

---

Maybe you could implement a resolve-uri extension function.

Comment: I was rather hoping for an xslt 1.0 solution.

Comment: @phiri: Write an extension function.

Answer (score 0):

Many XSLT 2.0 processors implement the collection() function in such a way as to allow you to interrogate directory structures in filestore. I'm not aware of any equivalent extensions in XSLT 1.0 processors.

Comment: thank you; however, my solution needs to make use of XSLT 1.0. On a side note, your XSLT programmer's reference book is a great source of help.