# document() function in XSLT1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to display a xml in a IE browser directly using xslt 1.0 without any engine.I could get some code from the source xml,then I want to get the corresponding displayname to this code from a external xml named voc.xml.but I could not get the displayname following these instructions
1.define a document variable in the xsl

```
<xsl:variable name="voc" select="document('voc.xml')"/>
```

2.get the code following my own xpath and I can get the value of   the variable 'paytypecode'='01'
3.find the corresponding code in the voc.xml

```
<xsl:variable name='mappedpaytypecode' select="$voc//systems/system[@root='CV07.10.003医疗费用来源类别代码表']/code[@value='01']"/>
```

4.get the displayName of this corresponding code in the voc.xml

```
<xsl:variable name='displayName_value' select="$mappedpaytypecode/@displayname"/>
```

and the voc.xml is like this

```
<systems>
    <system codeSystemName="CV07.10.003医疗费用来源类别代码表" root="CV07.10.003医疗费用来源类别代码表">
       <code value="01" displayname="城镇职工基本医疗保险" />
       <code value="02" displayname="城镇居民基本医疗保险" />
       <code value="03" displayname="新型农村合作医疗" />
       <code value="04" displayname="贫困救助" />
       <code value="05" displayname="商业医疗保险" />
       <code value="06" displayname="全公费" />
       <code value="07" displayname="全自费" />
       <code value="99" displayname="其他" />      
  </system> 
</systems>
```

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? Also what engine?

Comment: 1.0 and without engine.I just want to use this xslt to display the source xml in a browser

Comment: That means your engine is the browser.

Comment: Note: that there is an error in your voc.xml. The end-tag is incorrect. That may prevent your document from loading.

Comment: do you have any idea?It seems there is nothing wrong with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three issues here:

1. Your sample input document is malformed. Please inspect the closing tag of the <systems> element.
2. XPath is case-sensitive. In your select expression for the $displayName_value variable, you have used camel-case ('@displayName'), but in your input document, you have used lower-case ('@displayname');
3. You did not mention the range of browsers you are testing on. If FF (desktop) or IE, you are ok. Please note that Google Chrome (desktop) will not allow local-system XSLT. This is by design. I don't know if mobile browsers support client-side XSLT or not.

### IE Browser

Don't forget to use the node-set() function. References:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz88kef0.aspx
2. http://dpcarlisle.blogspot.com.au/2007/05/exslt-node-set-function.html
3. [How to use node-set function in a platform-independent way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92076/how-to-use-node-set-function-in-a-platform-independent-way)

Comment: thank u.the first two is my type error.the third one browser is IE.

Comment: you mean I replace the xslt document function with EXSLT extension common node set?

Comment: No. In XSLT 1.0 (not so in 2.0), you need to convert node-sets into document tree fragments. If only using IE, then stick with the msxsl:node-set() . Otherwise use exslt:node-set() .